# What does いきなりはじめんといてよ mean

Tags: meaning, dialects, kansai-ben

from what I know, does it mean "starts from all of a sudden"?
I thought the sentence could be separated as いきなり+ はじめん+といてよ？

Answer (score 6):

In Kansai we say 「～～んといて（よ）」 to mean 「～～しないで（よ）」, "(Please) Don't do~~."

So いきなりはじめんといてよ means いきなりはじめないでよ, "Don't start all of a sudden." or "Don't start so abruptly".

I would parse it as:「いきなり(suddenly) + はじめ(verb 始める) + ん(negative auxiliary verb) + と(conjunctive particle) + いて(subsidiary verb いる -- (maybe the といて is derived from て+おいて?)) + よ(sentence ending particle)」.

Other examples:

> 行かんといてよ。 Don't go.
>   しゃべらんといてよ。 Don't talk.
>   触らんといてよ。 Don't touch (it/me/etc.).
>   近寄らんといて。 Don't come close (to me/someone/something).

Comment: （すごく）どうでもいいのですが、関西弁の否定命令ってこの形以外ないんでしたっけ？

Comment: うーむ、ほかに…「始めんときー。」「行かんときー。」とか(←アドバイスっぽい感じで「行かないでおきなさい」っぽい)　「始めんな。」「しゃべんな。」(←これって関東と同じ？ちょっときつい感じ)　「行かんとけ。」「しゃべらんとけ。」(←乱暴・男っぽい)　とかですかね・・。　「～しないでよ。」に最も近い感じがするのは「～しんといてよ。」「～しんといてーさ。」「～しんといてんか。」くらいかな、と思います

Comment: 「な」もあるんですね…最初思ったのは、これは「～ておく」由来じゃないのかなということだったので（関東の「～といて」はこういう使い方しないですが）

Comment: 「行かないでおいて」-> 「行かんといて」 ってことですよね。そうかも・・わかんないｗ

Comment: あ、でも「行かんて」っていう語形はないんでしたっけ。「行かんでええ」でしたよね…

Comment: 「行かんて」はないですね・・「行って」はあるのに。「行かないで」をそのまんま関西弁にすると「行かんで」になりそうなのに。